# Need some help with a RegEx query

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given the following string:

```
someObject.SomeFunction.parameters[0] = new Thing('ValueName', 0);
```

How to I get just the `ValueName` value? - using C#

Comment: Also just to be clear, I'm trying to parse the above string with C# - not actually use javascript.

Comment: Is every part of the provided string constant (will never change) except for `ValueName`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) method or using regex:

```
(?<=')(?:\\'|[^'])*(?=')
```

e.g.:

```
Regex.Match(input, @"(?<=')(?:\\'|[^'])*(?=')").Value
```